# GWT MVP: Same view for different objects?

Tags: gwt, mvp

I thought a lot about [Building Large Scale Applications and MVP](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture) Part I + II.

Let's say, I have three objects e.g. Companies, Contacts and Furniture.

Let's assume that these three objects can be viewed, edited and added and have relations with each other.

Would I really have

- `CompaniesView.ui.xml`, `ContactView.ui.xml`, `FurnitureView.ui.xml`
- `CompaniesEdit.ui.xml`, `ContactEdit.ui.xml`, `FurnitureEdit.ui.xml`
- `CompaniesViewImpl.java`, `ContactViewImpl.java`, `FurnitureViewImple.java`
- 3x `*View.java`
- 3x `Edit*ViewImpl.java`
- 3x `Edit*View.java`
- 3x `*Presenter`
- Millions of Events
- 3x `*ColumnsDefinitionsFactory`
- 3x `CompaniesServiceAsync.java`, `ContactsServiceAsync.java`, `FurnitureServiceAsync.java` for the RPCs
- I would have nine tokens in my AppController: `"companiesList"`, `"contactList"`, `"furnitureList"`, 3x `"*Add"`, 3x `"*Edit"`
- ...

Am I on the right way? Is it just normal that the application gets bigger at this way?

I could also view the three objects in the same view called `ObjectView.ui.xml`.
I guess that's why generics (`<T>`) are used in the article?

But then I have fear that I can not realize differences any more given due to my object design e.g. that I have a button ImportContacts but no button ImportCompanies.

How do you recommend I should extend my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the use case, but I would have a view and a Representer for each object, because basically the create/edit/view represent the same data and usually have the same layout, thus they could be made in on view and set some kind of modes.

But if the use case dictate completely different views layout, in that case you may create three views with tree displays interfaces attached to one Presenter.

[Best Practices for Architecting GWT App 2009](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDuhR18-EdM&feature=relmfu)

[Best Practices for Architecting GWT App 2010](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5x6E6ze1x8)

Comment: Thanks! Would you recommend to use one or three different RPCs?

Comment: It depends on the scale of the application. I would have one RPC interface by domain, for example for user management I would have a RPC service that contains CRUD operations on user and other user related methods. The use of command pattern and dependency injection is also recommended. I added two good videos by Ray Ryan that explains the best practices for a GWT app.